# Cannot start i3

Tags: i3-window-manager, ubuntu-18.04

So I made a clean i3 install on my laptop and wanted to test some themes (I've only used vanilla i3 on my Debian PC before). I have Ubuntu 18.04 installed.

I followed the instructions [here](https://github.com/unix121/i3wm-themer), but now when I try to select i3 from the log in screen, I just get a black screen for a second, followed by the log in screen again.

I tried to fix it using the suggestions [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/i3wm/comments/5sjm9t/clean_install_of_i3_wont_start/) to no avail. I'm out of ideas. What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out this was caused by my current i3 installation conflicting with i3-gaps. I removed i3-wm and reinstalled and it worked fine.

Comment: Can you please explain how you did that  ?